# How to reset a graph by name in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My understanding about working with multiple tensorflow graphs is that if i am creating a graph with `tf.Graph()` then there are two graphs that tensorflow has created for me. One is the graph that tensorflow sets as default when i am within no context and one that i created using `tf.Graph()` that will be default when i am within `tf.Graph().as_default():` context. Now, How do i go about resetting the  graph i created with tf.Graph() since `tf.reset_default_graph()` [cannot be used](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11121) inside a `tf.Graph().as_default():` context

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `tf.Graph()` and replace the previous one. As long as you remember to replace all of the references, the old graph will be garbage collected, so this solution is equivalent to resetting your existing graph.

Just remember about all of the references! You would likely need to recreate the session that used the previous graph, as I don't think that there is a way to just replace the graph reference.

Comment: Old graph wont be garbage collected. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14181

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder this is unexpected. I'm sorry but I don't have any better idea. Maybe you'll have more luck working with eager execution. Certainly, there is some different GC policy there.

Comment: as your answer does not provide a solution, i cannot upvote it. I appreciate you helping. For the time being I am going ahead with deleting the graph when it is not needed with good old del command